# My CSS menu bar works in firefox but not chrome

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

Hi I've been working on my new website and after testing it in Firefox I can't interact with the nav bar in chrome. Does anyone have any suggestions?

http://jsbin.com/oFACIVE/2/edit?html,css,output

and in context of the site

http://jsbin.com/oFACIVE/3/edit

Comment: Seems fine on my chrome & firefox. What can't you interact with?

Comment: Looks like a `z-index` problem, try `#navigation { z-index: 9999; }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#navigation { 
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 45px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: 125px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #fefefe;
  width: auto;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I haven't enough reputation for a comment, so I have to answer directly.

In case you don't have any other z-indexes, you could simply put the container at the end of your html structure (making it the last div in body). Therefore, you would just use the 'natural order' of elements. I handled a similar problem that way, since I don't like playing around with z-indexes.

Of course, this works only if your navigation is positioned absolute/fixed.